# All SATA connected drives are generating errors in event log even after changing the motherboard

Tags: windows-10, ssd, sata

Background:
I have three SATA connected drives besides my NVMe system drive:

1. Old samsung 8** series SSD
2. Old WD 3TB HDD
3. New 1TB Crucial SSD

For some time now i was experiencing audio shuttering and random few seconds freezes as well as some minor USB problems so i thought my core 8-gen (Aourus k3?) motherboard south bridge must be on his last legs and I made an overdue upgrade to a new motherboard - this time ASUS TUF GAMING B550-PLUS.

Now i was surprised that i could run the OS from the NVMe without reinstall and all my problems were gone or so i thought - i was wrong.

About a week ago i noticed the system started hanging on the POST screen logo for a few seconds on every boot. I tried removing possible problematic devices and disconnecting the HDD drive "fixed" the problem - the PC boots without interruption now.

OK, I thought - maybe the HDD is old and worn out - I could hear it spinning up and down from time to time so I suspected a failure despite no SMART problems. Oh well, I'll buy a new one later.

Two days ago my old SSD starts to disappear and reappear while I'm doing something resulting in explorer window popping out... Mildly infuriating... Moved the pagefile to the gaming 1TB SSD and disconnected the old one - can't be bothered by that now.

Yesterday I wanted to play some WoWs and I'm getting 3-4 second freezes and some textures wont load. Event log is littered with error 51 - pagefile error and other SATA disk related errors.

I'm slowly loosing my mind here...

Two things I'm considering now:

1. Replace SATA cables - this is kind of stupid since the SATA cable is a very simple device that should not fail.
2. Replace the PSU - this would be costly and i have no other symptoms of failing PSU I can think of.

I can provide any log and other information but please help me get this sorted out.

Thanks in advance

Edit: i tried reinstalling chipset and SATA/RAID drivers from ASUS website - no effect. Switching the SATA controller to RAID mode made things worse - system crashes when trying to install drivers.
RAM is running in XMP mode - 4x8GB @ 3200Mhz

Comment: Did you install ALL motherboard drivers for your new motherboard ? It needs different drivers and Windows 10 is NOT always using the best ones on its own (in my experience it keeps using the old drivers instead of upgrading them if they "sort-of work" with the new motherboard). Furthermore pagefile related errors (and unstable SATA) could be a result of RAM timing issues. Make sure your run your RAM at the normal speed for that RAM. Use CPU-z (or similar tool, don't rely on what bios shows you) to check what speed the RAM really runs.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with an similar issue - it seams the problem was the case - not the PSU. My case has a small circuit that controls all the fans using one motherboard connector - after disconnecting circuit and lightning from the psu and connecting individual fans directly to the motherboard the problem seems fixed although i have only one SSD connected ATM.